# What are the differences between "taking advantage" and "leverage"?

Tags: grammar, expression-choice

What are the differences between "to take advantage" and "leverage"?

I have thought about that and got 2 points:

1. as a verb, "leverage" is only acceptable in American English, [this post](http://this.isfluent.com/2010/1/are-you-stupid-enough-to-use-leverage-as-a-verb/) has explained that in detail.
2. when used with a derogatory sense, for example:

> "I was taken advantage of by the two bullies"

Could "leverage" have taken its place?

Comment: _psst..._ "I was **taken** advantage of..."

Comment: "leverage" is MBA speak

Answer (score 1):

English is the most flexible language I've ever heard of but I don't think that using "*[leverage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leverage)*" as a verb is (yet) all that popular. Anyway as a verb it appears to mean just "*to use [as] a lever*" in its literal and translate senses, and as such it might assume the meaning "*to abuse sb.*" or "*to take advantage of sb.*" only if the lever were to be used as a weapon.

Thus I'd recommend to stick with the good old "*to take advantage of --*"

Answer (score 1):

In most instances I find of using ***leverage*** as a verb meaning to "take advantage of", it is in a financial context. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20leverage&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cto%20leverage%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bto%20leverage%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20Leverage%3B%2Cc0) shows the usage of "leverage" as a verb is on the rise since 1970.

> More Strategic Approach in Funding Airport Improvement Grants Could Improve Airline Industry Efficiency FAA and the Congress have an opportunity to **leverage** the almost *$2 billion annual budget* for the Airport Improvement Program (AIP) in ...

--[Airline Competition: Options for Addressing Financial and Competition](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=qgg6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA17&dq=%22to%20leverage%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20leverage%22&f=false)  (1993)

> Consortiums allow employers to “**leverage**” *their money* and provide services that would be too costly to provide alone.

-[The Changing Workforce: Highlights of the National Study](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=VQDfuOrR1tcC&pg=PA67&dq=%22to%20leverage%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20leverage%22&f=false) (1993)

I did find a usage in non-financial:

> Computer-based tools can be used **to leverage** *the experience and time* of instructional designers: for instance, we've created a hypertext instructional design tool to aid us in documenting and managing courseware development.

[-Multimedia for Learning: Development, Application, Evaluation](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=q7E1UY76KcAC&pg=PA10&dq=%22to%20leverage%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20leverage%22&f=false)

In fact, it is found in the [Cambridge on-line](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leverage):

> to use something that you already have in order to achieve something new or better:
>
> "We can gain a market advantage by leveraging our network of partners."

I would not use this verb to describe an altercation with bullies unless they are working in the financial or political sector.